# Deleting the used part of cStringIO.StringIO

Tags: python, string, exception

```
import os, sys
from cStringIO import StringIO
import traceback

old_stdErr = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = mystdErr = StringIO()

try:
    p = 100/0
except Exception:
     traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)

print mystdErr.getvalue()             ### -- 1st Print statement 

try:
   q = 100/0
except Exception:
   traceback.print_exc(file = sys.stderr)

print mystdErr.getvalue()             ### -- 2nd Print statement
```

This piece of code .. What the output will be

#### Output from the 1st print statement

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manojtut\Desktop\untitled-1.py", line 9, in 
    p = 100/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

#### Output from the 2nd print statement

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manojtut\Desktop\untitled-1.py", line 9, in 
    p = 100/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manojtut\Desktop\untitled-1.py", line 16, in 
    q = 100/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

As you can see , the exception encountered at 1st zerodivision is being printed again in the second print statement which I don't want. Can I somehow eliminate/flush away the first  exception traceback so that only the second exception's traceback can be printed in the second print statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
mystdErr.reset()
mystdErr.truncate()
```

before the second block. `reset` resets the file position to the beginning and writing begins from there. `truncate` removes all data after the current position. If 'truncate' is omitted - the data in the stream will be overwritten from subsequent writes.

Comment: Didn't find the references of reset function before. Thanks mate.

Comment: reset() seems undocumented; use rather the equivalent `seek(0)` to remain on the documented path

Comment: Also, reset() doesn’t exist in Python 3.